# How does an illuminated 3-way toggle switch advertised as "illuminated when off" know that it is off?

Tags: electrical, lighting

Since the lighting can be off with a 3-way or 4-way toggle switch in either the up or down position depending on what the other switch is doing, how does a toggle switch operate the light to "*illuminate when it is off*"?  Is it only on when the switch handle is in the down position?

The advertising data states:

> - PERFORMANCE - Designed to work with LED, CFL and incandescent loads,
>   no neutral required
> - SAFE - Switch remains illuminated in the OFF position, so it is easy
>   to locate in a dark room

The use of the word "remains", here, could imply that it is also on when the handle is in the ON position.

Is this merely marketing buzz-words and the light is always on but you simply cannot tell with the room's main lights on, or does the switch actually detect a lack of power continuity on the main switch to turn on the backlight in either position?

So, I see three possibilities:

1. The backlight is *always on* but too dim to see in a lit room.
2. The switch only connects the backlight power when the toggle is in the down position regardless of what the room's lights are doing.
3. There is some mechanism that only illuminates the switch when there is no power passing through the main switch contacts regardless of the handle position.

Does anyone know?  The product line I'm specifically interested in is LED-compatible Leviton illuminated switches.

Second question: Does the location of the illuminated switch in the circuit matter?  In my case, it will be downstream of a line conductor --> 3-way sw. --> 4-way sw. --> illuminated 3-way sw., then the lights.

Comment: Or is this a translation error? Saw a translation of light switch instructions once that said "Light on, Dark on" for the two positions...

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure  that it is the same switch, but I have a Leviton 3 way in my dining room and the light on the switch is always on.

Comment: Odd, I have Levitron 3-ways where the switch illumination is (clearly) only on when the lights are off. The reddish backlight is easy to distinguish even in normal lighting conditions (often one switch of a pair is well illuminated by lights other than what that switch controls).

Comment: Downvoting this question because 1) it is about a specific product, 2) you haven't identified the product or provided its documentation 3) you are asking how it achieves a thing, but the thing isn't even defined.  How does it know the switch is off?  But we don't even know if the light is on all the time so maybe it doesn't know .. there isn't really a question here.

Comment: @jay613 Curiously, your comment highlights a Catch-22 in this question. Your point 1 isn't actually true yet, as of the time of my comment here. No model number has been posted yet, so no specific product is being inquired about. But to satisfy your points 2 and 3, a model number must be posted, which would "entruth" your point 1.

Comment: @RyanMortensen, in order to have an idea about how this switch might work, we'd need to know what switch you're looking at. Manufacturer and model number, please.  Given the possibilities in electronics nowadays, there could be lots of ways this could be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was "how does it work?" This is an answer to the unasked question of "can I use this device?"

As far as *how* it works: there are a bunch of ways that would have been expensive and/or bulky years ago - *TL;DR the magic of microchips*.

There are 4 main ways to provide a "lighted when off" switch, or to power a smart switch:

- Battery - Not likely here.
- Leak current through load - Not likely here because that is generally incompatible with LED and CFL.
- Neutral - it says "no neutral required"
- Ground

The problem with ground is that it *works* but it is often **NOT CODE COMPLIANT**. It is *possible* to have a properly designed device that uses minimal current legitimately use ground. But I would not trust that except on a product that is UL or ETL or equivalent (not CE, not FCC, not TM, not (C), not ROHS, etc.) listed.

So if this thing is UL or ETL listed, go for it. Otherwise, throw it back.  And if you have a neutral get something that requires neutral - that solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses ground as neutral to power the illumination.

also note that it doesn't claim to be dark when on, only that it remains illuminated when off.